# Find the phone number of a contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a list of contacts (names), and when user presses a certain name, I want to get the phone number of that contact.

I'm using a `Cursor` and today my projection is:

```
static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Data._ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY};
```

I want to add another column that will hold the phone number: something like:

```
static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Data._ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHONE_NUMBER};
```

But I can not find how to do this.
Please help

Comment: `and when user press a cretin name` - hm. why you insult your users' contacts? ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about [ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html)?
So, something like:

```
static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Data._ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
   ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER};
```

Comment: I get run time exception before I even see the list created. when I add something like ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER - it works fine, and I get the data

Comment: @DuduArbel, what is the exception you experience specifically(or message)?